# Sort array based on another one

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I got two arrays:

```
let arrayValues = [["20", "."], ["42", "."], ["44", "."], ["6", "."], ["5", "."]]
let arrayIndex = [4,5,1,2,3]
```

and I got one Problem:

I'd like to sort the **values** array based on the numbers of the index Array -  *(note that the **first Element** is connected to the first Element, the second one to the second and so on)* - so that the highest number comes first, the second next and so one. This order needs to be translated to the first array.

The result should be this:

```
let result = ["42", "."], ["20", "."], ["5", "."], ["6", "."], ["44", "."]]
```

because of the new order

```
= [5,4,3,2,1]
```

---

I now my question deals with a super special problem - but I got no idea how to start tbh.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Heres my python code:

```
arrayValues = (("20", "."), ("42", "."), ("44", "."), ("6", "."), ("5", "."))
arrayIndex = (4,5,1,2,3)
result = sorted(range(len(arrayValues)), key=lambda i:arrayIndex[i],reverse=0)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And remember that "sorting" doesn't need to be in place. Building a new array and throwing away the old one(s) is usually perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the indices, soert them by the values at this index and map the values in the new order.

```js
var values = [["20", "."], ["42", "."], ["44", "."], ["6", "."], ["5", "."]],
    order = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
    result = [...order.keys()]
        .sort((a, b) => order[b] - order[a])
        .map(i => values[i]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the indices:

```
  const result = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < arrayValues.length && i < arrayIndex.length; i++)
    result[ arrayIndex[i] - 1 ] = arrayValues[i];
```